# Issue with Bootstrap Navbar Toggle Button not working

Tags: html, css

Wondering why my Bootstrap toggler isn't working. Viewed a few other thread on a similar issue appearing, but didn't find an appropriate solution since everything seems in order.

```
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Frontend Bootcamp</a>\
        <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navmenu"
      >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#learn" class="nav-link">What You'll Learn</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#questions" class="nav-link">Questions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#instructors" class="nav-link">Instructors</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
</html>
```

Comment: I need some more information about this (please paste the complete HTML). At this point, it could be a multitude of issues. Did you load in your JS files properly? Is your button element pointing to the right piece of data? I also noticed you didn't close your `</body>` tag.

Comment: have you linked bootstrap js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are questioning why your icon does not appear, it's because of it's color, use `text-white` class to make it visible (or add `.navbar-inverse` to your navbar)

if your collapse is not working it's probably because you did not link bootstrap.js in your project

https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiar_mansouri/3u5jvw1d/5/

this fiddle is based on your code, it has the icon visible (two icons actually, one from bs itself another from bootstrap icon package) and it's collapse is working fine

Comment: Thank you so much! Was the bootstrap.js which wasn't linked. I thought I had done so already.

Comment: you're welcome that's one of the most common issues in BS :)